# React Router createBrowserRouter nested paths not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the code below

```jsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage></HomePage>,
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    element: <LoginPage></LoginPage>,
    children: [
      { path: "store", element: <StoreLoginPage /> },
      { path: "master", element: <ClientLoginPage /> },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "Dashboard",
    element: <DashboardPage />,
  },
]);
```

the path `"/login/store"` and `"/login/master"` both render `<LoginPage/>` which should only map to the path `"/login"`. I can't figure out why this is not working. The docs say the nested paths should be in the `children` array.

Answer (score 1):

While it is correct that nested routes are specified as children of a parent route, the routed elements are only rendered through an `Outlet` component rendered by the parent route's element. In this case the layout route `LoginPage` component should be rendering an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { ..., Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested route render content here
    ...
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />,
  },
  {
    path: "login",
    element: <LoginPage />,
    children: [
      { path: "store", element: <StoreLoginPage /> },
      { path: "master", element: <ClientLoginPage /> },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "Dashboard",
    element: <DashboardPage />,
  },
]);
```

For more details see [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets).